# java handling optional primitives

Tags: java

We are using Java (1.7) for our application and I have got the below **Train** class:

```
public class Train {

    private String number;

    private String origin;

    private String destination;

    public Train(String number, String origin, String destination) {
        //set the fields
    }

    //other fields

    private int latenessAtOriginInMinutes;//optional Field

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Assume that the field `latenessAtOriginInMinutes` is optional**, when I instantiate the object  `Train train = new Train(1234, "A", "B")`, 
the `latenessAtOriginInMinutes` will get the value 0 (which is the default for `int` types) for the object referenced by `train`, 
so then **how can I differentiate that the 'lateness' is really zero or is it the default value (of primitive `int`) set by the JVM?**

One way to solve this problem is simply **setting `latenessAtOriginInMinutes=99999` (some high default value)** initially through the constructor,
but each time when I retrieve the value from the database, I need to check that the value is `latenessAtOriginInMinutes != 99999` to find the real lateness value, which I did not like.

The other way is to use `OptionalInt` in Java8, but we are currently using Java 1.7.

The other alternative is declaring `latenessAtOriginInMinutes` type as **Integer**, but I am not sure if this is the best option.

So, my question is, what is the best way to handle the optional fields like `latenessAtOriginInMinutes`?

Comment: Use an Integer, leave it to null by default.

Comment: You seem so determined to use a primitive? Why not use an object wrapper which can be `null`?

Comment: I thought about that i.e., wrapper classes (will add to the above), but I am thinking if there is any other better option?

Comment: Use Guava's Optional? Use a better marker value than 9999, like -1? Define a Lateness type that tells if lateness has been set or not. It's up to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't take -1 as -1 can be a value for lateness (if the train departs early), so taken higher positive value.

Comment: @PVS in that case, try `Integer.MAX_VALUE`